# Connection between Barnette conjecture and hardness of cubic graph decomposition

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

Motivated by this post on [cubic graphs decompositions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156455/cubic-graphs-decompositions) and the connection to Barnette's conjecture, I am interested in decomposing a connected bridgeless cubic graph into edge-disjoint paths of length 3 (P4). My intuition is that it should be $NP$-complete but did not find a reduction.

Barnette's conjecture states that every 3-connected cubic bipartite planar graph is Hamiltonian. This is equivalent to decomposing every such graph into Hamiltonian cycle and a perfect matching. [Feder and Subi](http://theory.stanford.edu/~tomas/barnew.pdf) proved that if there is a single graph in the class of the conjecture which does not admit such decomposition then deciding the existence of Hamiltonian cycle in $NP$-complete in that class.

> Is it $NP$-complete to decide whether a bridgeless cubic bipartite graph is decomposable into edge-disjoint paths of length 3 (P4)?

The linked post on MathOverflow provides some interesting examples of connected cubic graph decomposition problems.

> For general connected cubic graph decomposition problems, under which conditions does the existence of a non-decomposable graph (in some class) imply the $NP$-completeness of the decomposition decision problem? Is there a subclass of connected bridgeless cubic graphs where a non-decomposable graphs exist but it is polynomial time to decide the existence of a (edge) decomposition?

The decomposition decision problem should be non-trivial.

(I am aware that it is $NP$-complete to decide whether a cubic bipartite planar graph is decomposable into vertex-disjoint paths of length 2 (P3))

The problem was posted on [TCS SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/30817/is-it-np-complete-to-decompose-bridgeless-cubic-bipartite-graph-into-edge-disj).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easy to prove the following result:

Proposition. Every bridgeless cubic graph admits a decomposition into paths of length 3.

Petersen (1891) proved that every bridgeless bipartite graph contains a perfect matching (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen%27s_theorem).

Koztig (57) proved that a cubic graph G admits a decomposition into paths of length 3 if and only if G contains a perfect matching.

Comment: thank you. Do you have a link for the second reference?

Comment: Has to be this: @article {MR0090815,
    AUTHOR = {Kotzig, Anton},
     TITLE = {Aus der {T}heorie der endlichen regul\"aren {G}raphen dritten
              und vierten {G}rades},
   JOURNAL = {\v Casopis P\v est. Mat.},
  FJOURNAL = {\v Ceskoslovensk\'a Akademie V\v ed. \v Casopis Pro P\v
              estov\'an\'\i\ Matematiky},
    VOLUME = {82},
      YEAR = {1957},
     PAGES = {76--92},
      ISSN = {0528-2195},
   MRCLASS = {55.0X},
  MRNUMBER = {0090815 (19,876c)},
MRREVIEWER = {M. Fiedler},
}

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the correct paper.